# Bug in pandas.io.data.DataReader

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am getting data from Yahoo using pandas.io.data.DataReader, how come the "Date" position is shifted downward? how could I fix it by moving "Date" to first row?

```
             Open   High    Low  Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                      
2014-04-16  22.95  22.95  21.95  22.35  4198000      21.35
```

Comment: This is just the text representation of the DataFrame object. This means that `Date` is set as the index of your dataframe

Comment: This is not a bug as Joris has stated, if you want it as a column then call `reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the Date is index, that's why it's display in this form. Nothing need to worry about.